# How to dynamically add text files in a given directory, in Java?

Tags: java

I am using Eclipse. I want to read number of XML files from a directory. Each XML file contains multiple body tags. I want to extract values of all the body tags. My problem is I have to save each body tag value (text) in a separate .txt file and add these text files in another given directory. Can you plz help how can I create dynamically .txt file and add them in a specified directory?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First specify directory path and name

```
File dir=new File("Path to base dir");
if(!dir.exists){
dir.mkdir();}
```

//then generate File name

```
String fileName="generate required fileName";
File tagFile=new File(dir,fileName+".txt");
if(!tagFile.exists()){
tagFile.createNewFile();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add import for java.io.File;

```
File f;
f=new File("myfile.txt");
if(!f.exists()){
f.createNewFile();
```

replace "myfile.txt" to path to file you needed and file will be created when you say
e.g. "c:\\somedir\\yourfile.txt"

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs, it is now generating files dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this.

```
try {
    //Specify directory
    String directory = //TODO....
    //Specify filename
    String filename= //TODO....
    // Create file 
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(directory+filename+".txt");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    //insert your xml content here
    out.write("your xml content");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    //Close the output stream
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs, it is now generating files dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why you have mentioned the XML part. But it seems that you are able to get the text from XML file and wanted to write to separate text file.

Please go through this basic tutorial for creating, reading and writing files in Java: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

```
Path logfile = ...;

//Convert the string to a byte array.
String s = ...;
byte data[] = s.getBytes();

OutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(logfile.newOutputStream(CREATE, APPEND));
    ...
    out.write(data, 0, data.length);
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
} finally {
    if (out != null) {
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. Actually, I  have to extract text from XML file and put each text line in a separate .txt file.